# my functions are not executing in series even after using async.series

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

```
var async = require('async');
var connection = require('../../models/connection/connection').connection;
var about_model = require('../../models/about/about_model')(connection);

module.exports = {
    getAboutInfo: function(req, res) {

        async.series([

            function(callback) {

                about_model.getDob(req.params.id, function(err, rows) {
                    dob = rows[0].user_dob;
                });
                callback();
            },
            function(callback) {
                console.log(dob);
                callback();
            }
        ], function(err) {
            if(err) throw err;
            else
                res.render('about', {
                    title: "About Page",
                    dob: dob
                });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some text to explain what you expected, what actually happens, what you tried to solve the issue, ...

Comment: sir , i want that these functions to execute serially ... but these are not working in this way. in second function console.log(dob) is printing undefined.. and i also not able to get the value of dob at res.render

Answer (score 2):

The point of a callback in `async` functions is to tell `async` when you're finished.  In

```
        function(callback) {

            about_model.getDob(req.params.id, function(err, rows) {
                dob = rows[0].user_dob;
            });
            callback();
        }
```

you call `callback` before the operation is complete, so `async` thinks you're done even though you're not.  If you move that:

```
        function(callback) {

            about_model.getDob(req.params.id, function(err, rows) {
                dob = rows[0].user_dob;
                callback();
            });

        }
```

then it should work as you expect.